# Log of Average v. Average of Log

Tags: regression, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution, mean

I am constructing a dataset of monthly averages based on daily data. This dataset will be used for standard regression analysis. I anticipate wanting to transform the dependent variable, which has an approximately log-normal distribution. My question is whether it is more appropriate to transform the data before or after taking the monthly average.

Comment: If you do it before taking the average then you actually work in terms of geometric averages:  $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N log(x_i)=log\left({(\prod_{i=1}^N x_i})^{\frac{1}{N}}\right)$

Comment: If you are hoping to learn about the monthly averages but you conduct a regression on their logarithms, you will usually not obtain what you are looking for, in the same way that a geometric mean of data is not necessarily a good estimator of the arithmetic mean. Please tell us, then, about the objectives of your regression analysis.

Comment: There are a few possible objectives. One is to determine what share of the variation in the dependent variable is explained by a set of explanatory variables. The other is to measure the response of the dependent variable to a before / after dummy variable. In both cases, I am aware that performing the analysis in logs will require some additional work to interpret the effects in levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain the assumption that the *daily* dependent variable $Y_{ji}$ of month $i$ follows a log-normal distribution, this means that

$$\ln Y_{ji} \sim \mathbf N (\mu_{ji}, \sigma_{ji}^2)$$

Then, denoting $d_i$ the number of days of month $i$, we also have

$$ \frac {1}{d_i} \ln Y_{ji} \sim \mathbf  N\left(\frac {\mu_{ji}}{d_i}, \frac  {\sigma_{ji}^2}{d_i^2}\right)$$

If you also maintain the assumption that your sample is comprised of independent observations, the sum of independent normal random variables is certain to also follow a normal distribution and so

$$\sum_{j=1}^{d_i}\frac {1}{d_i} \ln Y_{ji} =\frac {1}{d_i} \sum_{j=1}^{d_i}\ln Y_{ji}  \sim N\left(\frac {1}{d_i} \sum_{j=1}^{d_i}\mu_{ji}, \frac {1}{d_i^2} \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} \sigma_{ji}^2\right)$$

In words, if a log-normality assumption is stated at the level of a sample of independent daily data, then the monthly average of the logs of the original daily variables (their geometric mean, as a comment mentioned) will also be normally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what is log-normally distributed?

I'm assuming it's monthly series. In this case get the average, then log.

If you thought that the daily series are log-normally distributed, then your average monthly series would be very close to normal distribution if there is no large autocorrelation.